# "UnsupportedEncodingException: SHA" when using RSA in Client-Server Application

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on an instant messaging app in java. I tried to implement the RSA Algorithm as discussed in [Demonstrate the use of RSA Public-key system to exchange messages that achieve confidentiality and integrity/authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20110684) with its solution provided but the received message is not getting decrypted correctly.

[image]

**Stack Trace**:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: SHA
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:190)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:426)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:491)
    at mychatappp.networking.MessageListener.decryptMessage(MessageListener.java:87)
    at mychatappp.networking.MessageListener.run(MessageListener.java:115)
```

**Server side run method**:

```java
ServerSocket server;
int listenPort = 8877;
WritableGUI gui;
LoginScreen sc = new LoginScreen();

public MessageListener(WritableGUI gui, int port){
    this.listenPort = port;
    this.gui = gui;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MessageListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public void decryptMessage(InputStream inStream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    try {

        //Create the Data input stream from the socket
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inStream);

        //Get the key
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("KeyFile.xx"));

        PrivateKey privatekey = (PrivateKey) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("Key Used: " + in.toString());
        in.close();

        //Initiate the cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");                        
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privatekey);

        int len = dis.readInt();
        byte[] encryptedMsg = new byte[len];
        dis.readFully(encryptedMsg);         

        System.out.println("Server - Msg Length: " + len);
        System.out.println("Server - Encrypted: " + asHex(encryptedMsg));

        // -Print out the decrypt String to see if it matches the original message.
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + new String(plainText, "SHA"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Function to make the bytes printable (hex format)
public static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
    StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            strbuf.append("0");
        }
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return strbuf.toString();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Socket clientSocket;

    try {
        while((clientSocket = server.accept()) != null){
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            decryptMessage(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
            String line = br.readLine();
            if(line != null){
                gui.write(line);
            }
        }
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Does SHA mean SHA1? If so, is the machine producing the exception in a FIPS configuration? Otherwise, it sounds like something is getting crossed in the signature encoding method where the formatting function is applied.

Comment: @jww So far, I have found out the problem is with computing signature part, I tried MD5, but same error came. Now except SHA in **stack trace** there was MD5. But I still don't understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: The stacktrace shows the error is coming from your `decryptMessage` method, but you haven’t included it. It looks like you are trying to pass the hash function name as the character encoding name when creating a String.

Comment: @matt Included the `decryptMessage` method.

Comment: As I suggested: `new String(plainText, "SHA")` is where the exception is coming from. What are you trying to do with that? If you just replace it with simply `plainText` it should work.

Comment: @matt Yea, now its working fine. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this snippet `new String(plainText, "SHA")`. SHA is not a character encoding. I don't know how your string is encoded (i.e. how characters are converted to bytes and vice versa) but you probably want `"UTF-8"` here.

Comment: Yep, now its working. Thanks for the solution mate, was stuck here for so long.